# Exceeded maximum execution time on Google App script with Google Big Query

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

How can I extend the execution time within my code below.  Essentially, I use Google App scripts to query data from our big query data base and export data on to Google spreadsheets.

The following is my code:

function Weekly_Metric(){

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetName = "Budget";
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
var sql = ' bigqueryscript ';
var results = GSReport.runQueryAsync(sql);
var resultsValues = GSReport.parseBigQueryAPIResponse(results); 
sheet.clear();
ss.appendRow(["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"]);

 for ( var i = 0 ; i < resultsValues.length ; i++ ) {
  ss.appendRow(resultsValues[i]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always reduce the number of calls to Google Apps Script services as much as you can.

In this case, the loop containing `appendRow()` can be replaced with javascript array operations and a single call to `setValues()`.

```
...
sheet.clear();

var data = [];
data.push(["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"]);
for ( var i = 0 ; i < resultsValues.length ; i++ ) {
  data.push(resultsValues[i]);
}
ss.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
...
```

Alternatively, if `resultsValues` is an array of rows already, you only need to add the labels:

```
...
sheet.clear();

resultsValues.unshift(["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"]);
ss.getRange(1,1,resultsValues.length,resultsValues[0].length).setValues(resultsValues);
...
```

If that doesn't do the trick, then you should look at your GSReport object's methods.